# Deserializing an anonymous object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm currently trying to deserialize a Json-feed that I'm receiving from an external process.
The problem is that the JSON is relying heavily on anonymous classes which I don't know how to properly deserialize.

I'm hoping anyone here could help me.

Below is a piece of the JSON:

```
[
  14,
  {
    "a": [
      "5877.40000",
      0,
      "0.89672653"
    ],
    "b": [
      "5877.30000",
      6,
      "6.20000000"
    ],
    "c": [
      "5877.40000",
      "0.02216247"
    ]
},
"name", 
"description"
]
```

So my class currently looks like this, but this is not correct:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public int ChannelID { get; set; } // 14 in the sample

        public TestSubClass test { get; set; } // THIS IS THE ANONYMOUS ONE

        public string ChannelName { get; set; } // "name" in the sample

        public string ChannelDescription { get; set; } // "description in the sample"
    }


    public class TestSubClass 
    {
        public TestOption1Class a { get; set; }
        public TestOption1Class b { get; set; }
        public TestOption2Class c { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestOption1Class 
    {
        public float price { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        public float unitWeight { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestOption2Class 
    {
        public float price { get; set; }
        public float unitWeight { get; set; }
    }
```

Now these classes are wrong. I am assuming I need to use some sort of key/value pair or something, but I'm not sure on how to achieve that.
If somebody know how I could deserialize this properly, that would be great.

In order to be complete, the code to deserialize is below:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestClass>>(jsonTest);
```

Comment: Why `TestSubClass` is an anonymous, if you know its structure? Is it always a 3 tokens inside it? Does it make sense to declare it as an array?

Comment: Yes,it's an array but it doesn't have a name, so I don't know how to deserialize it

Comment: Can you talk to author of the JSON to see if it can be set to makes a bit more sense (array of strings and numbers is very strange, especially since you trying to read those strings as `float`).

Comment: I agree that it's really strange, but no I can't ask to change the JSON since this being extracted from a piece of hardware.

Comment: How is it being "extracted" from a "piece of hardware"? What does that mean? Who is extracting it? How is being extracted?

Comment: I make a websocket connection to the device and I subscribe to a feed and this is what I'm receiving. The wonders of technology...

Comment: @Cainnech your entire json sample is an array, I don't think that you can deserialize it as a class intance with strongly typed properties. Can your share the complete sample?

Answer (score 1):

Since the anonymous type you're struggling with has keys and values, I think I would do away with the `TestSubClass` class altogether and try this instead:

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public int ChannelID { get; set; } // 14 in the sample

        public Dictionary<string, Array<object>> test { get; set; } // THIS IS THE ANONYMOUS ONE

        public string ChannelName { get; set; } // "name" in the sample

        public string ChannelDescription { get; set; } // "description in the sample"
    }
```

Deserialized, you would wind up with a Dictionary of Arrays containing Objects that you can then operate on with Double.TryParse() or Int32.TryParse() to get the proper values.

Comment: is that ``Dictionary<Array<object>>`` exist?

Comment: I get your point Rob, but actually the whole json is an array, I just didn't know that you could put different types in a array. So I will continue on this approach. Thank you!

Comment: Sajid: That type (actually combination of types) is available via the System.Collections.Generic namespace. It is a Dictionary<object>, and the object is of type Array<object>.

Comment: @RobJarvis the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` must have two type arguments - for keys and for values

Comment: @Impworks you are right--my apologies for the oversight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of strongly-typed classes for parts of the response structure you know and `JToken` for parts that can change and need to be inspected at runtime. Something like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int ChannelID { get; set; } // 14 in the sample

    [JsonProperty("test")]
    public JToken Test { get; set; } // THIS IS THE ANONYMOUS ONE

    public string ChannelName { get; set; } // "name" in the sample
    public string ChannelDescription { get; set; } // "description in the sample"
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>("...");
var test = data.Test;
if(test.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    // process as array
    foreach (JToken elem in test)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
else if(test.Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    // process as object
    foreach (JProperty kvp in test)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```